# is it necessay to implement Scanner interface along with Valuer interface

Tags: go, interface, go-gorm

I'm working on requirement wherein I receive a JSON object which contains a date value as a string. My task is to store the Date object in the DB.

Something of this sort:

```
{"start_date": "2019-05-29", "end_date": "2019-08-30"}
{"start_date": "2019-05-29", "end_date": null}
```

I have implemented the Custom `Date` type

```
type Date struct {
    time.Time
}
```

I have implemented UnmarshalJSON interface

```
func (d *Date) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    if b[0] == '"' && b[len(b)-1] == '"' {
        b = b[1 : len(b)-1]
    }

    // take care of null..
    if len(b) == 0 || string(b) == "null" {
        d.Time = time.Time{}
        return
    }

    d.Time, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02", string(b))
    return
}
```

also implemented the Valuer interface to return the Value to the sql.Driver.

```
func (d Date) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    // check if the date was not set..
    if d.Time.IsZero() {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return d.Time.Format("2006-01-02"), nil
}
```

But for some reason, **until** the Date implement the Scanner interface,
something like this:

```
func (d Date) Scan(b interface{}) (err error) {
    ...
    return
}
```

Question:

The ORM adapter (GORM) does not store the record in the DB. Any clue?

Full code listed [here](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/2ff1004baef56a18b87de0e415ba43a2)

To further elaborate..

If I run the above code 2 twice I see a different behaviour depending upon whether of not the Scan() function exist.

**1 time :**
database result

```
repl_test=# select id, start_date from customer_brokers;
 id | start_date
----+------------
  1 | 2019-05-29
```

All good now.. run the same code.. (commented the `Scan()` function)

**2nd time.**

```
repl_test=# select id, start_date from customer_brokers;
 id | start_date
----+------------
  1 | 2019-05-29
  2 |             <- start_date empty here..
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, but if you have problems implementing the `Scan` method, then that's because you're using a non-pointer receiver.

Comment: Thanks for the correction... the question was when I perform `DB.Create(&record)`  unless the Scanner interface is implemented `start_date` and `end_date` both appear (in the above case) as NULL in DB. If I implemented the Scanner interface I see the correct value in the DB. 

The Question is I don't need Scanner interface. Since the project just dump record in DB .. not reading anything back from DB.

Comment: Your question is confusing. But the title seems straight forward. `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer` are two sides of the same coin, analogous to `json.Unmarshaler` and `json.Marshaler`. That is to say, `sql.Scanner` is used when reading a value from the database, and `driver.Valuer` is used when writing a value to the database. Whether you need both depends on whether you need to both read and write data to the database.

Comment: @Flimzy, here is the thing.. If you can run the above code 2 time. 1 time without Scan method and 2 time with Scan method you would see that only the last inserted record would have value `2019-05-29` in the `start_date` column. That is my question..

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking. I've answered the title in a comment. The rest of your question seems unrelated to the title. I gather you're having trouble inserting data? All that matters for that (per my comment above) is the `Valuer` interface. But you haven't included the relevant code, so it's hard to tell why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the `DB.LogMode(true)` shows these two queries

with scan:

```
[2019-10-16 14:03:34]  [0.97ms]  INSERT  INTO "custom_brokers" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","start_date","end_date") VALUES ('2019-10-16 14:03:34','2019-10-16 14:03:34',NULL,'2019-05-29',NULL) RETURNING "custom_brokers"."id"
```

without scan:

```
[2019-10-16 14:02:53]  [0.76ms]  INSERT  INTO "custom_brokers" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at") VALUES ('2019-10-16 14:02:53','2019-10-16 14:02:53',NULL) RETURNING "custom_brokers"."id"
```

the second one shows that the gorm completely ignores the other column in the model (except for embeded gorm model)

After debuging it, I reaized on model creation, [here](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/ac78f05986ab456936afd148e629533d8d819289/model_struct.go#L219-L231), gorm checks if the field is `sql.Scanner` and then set the `IsNormal` field, which is used in query creation phase. if the field is not a `sql.Scanner`, the `IsNormal` is false so it's ignored [here](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/712c4655605f094d283047501ae613db9c798850/callback_create.go#L62)

so, the answer to your question is yes, you have to implement a `Scan` method even if you don't need to scan it.

Comment: @frerorubigd this seem like a legit answer to me.. but I'll cross check the code.. give me some time.

Answer (score 3):

Pre: I ran `go get -u github.com/jinzhu/gorm`. I will use `sqlite` instead of `pgsql`. fyi, `go version go1.12.7 linux/amd64`

1. your annotations are not using the correct syntax. The gorm-property-value pair's separator is **not** the `comma`, but the `semi-colon`. https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/model_struct.go#L644
2. The implementation of `Date.Scan()` must use a pointer receiver, otherwise you loose the updated value. https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/0fd395ab37aefd2d50854f0556a4311dccc6f45a/scaner_test.go#L57
3. during my tests, `Scan` method received a `time.Time`, thus no need of `nil` case, nor `string` case (might be a matter of db driver). However, **and more importantly**, i added a `default` case to catch for unsupported types.
4. The `Scan` method is involved during the assignation of the data read from the database to the objects you provided. Commenting it has nothing to do with the missing date issue you demonstrated in your last sql results copy-paste. I think this is somehow related to the previously mentioned issues i wrote about.
5. I listened all errors to ensure things were working as expected.

Here is my test code,

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

type CustomerBroker struct {
    gorm.Model
    StartDate Date `gorm:"type:date;column:start_date" json:"start_date"`
    EndDate   Date `gorm:"type:date;column:end_date" json:"end_date"`
}

type Date struct {
    time.Time
}

func (d *Date) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    if b[0] == '"' && b[len(b)-1] == '"' {
        b = b[1 : len(b)-1]
    }

    // take care of null..
    if len(b) == 0 || string(b) == "null" {
        d.Time = time.Time{}
        return
    }

    d.Time, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02", string(b))
    return
}

func (d *Date) Scan(b interface{}) (err error) {
    switch x := b.(type) {
    case time.Time:
        d.Time = x
  default:
    err = fmt.Errorf("unsupported scan type %T", b)
    }
    return
}

func (d Date) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    // check if the date was not set..
    if d.Time.IsZero() {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return d.Time.Format("2006-01-02"), nil
}

func main() {
    var dberr error
    DB, dberr = gorm.Open("sqlite3", ":memory:")
    if dberr != nil {
        panic(dberr)
    }
    defer DB.Close()
    record := CustomerBroker{}
    errs := DB.CreateTable(record).GetErrors()
    fmt.Println("create error ", errs)
    data := []byte(`{"start_date": "2019-05-29", "end_date": null}`)
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &record)
    fmt.Println("unmarshal error ", err)
    log.Printf("record start %v end %v\n", record.StartDate, record.EndDate)
    errs = DB.Create(&record).GetErrors()
    fmt.Println("insert error ", errs)
    all := []CustomerBroker{}
    errs = DB.Find(&all).GetErrors()
    fmt.Println("find error ", errs)
    log.Printf("records count %v\n", len(all))
    for _, a := range all {
        log.Printf("found start %v end %v\n", a.StartDate, a.EndDate)
    }
}
```

Outputs :

```
$ go run main.go 
create error  []
unmarshal error  <nil>
2019/10/11 17:22:51 record start 2019-05-29 00:00:00 +0000 UTC end 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
insert error  []
find error  []
2019/10/11 17:22:51 records count 1
2019/10/11 17:22:51 found start 2019-05-29 00:00:00 +0000 UTC end 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

If you find a different behavior when running this against `pqsql`, please share the corresponding docker image so future attempts can occur against the same version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I believe we still haven't address the real question. The question that **why do I need to implement Scanner interface** to insert the record in DB (my project does not deal with reading data from database).


If I **do not** implement the Scanner interface. The record in DB goes are nil. 

On hindsight if you write a *bare dummy* __Scan() function with `return nil` that works.__

And you would see the DB contain the correct value inside of NULL. As I had explained in my question.

Comment: ?? any thought on the comment?

Comment: any clue on this?

Comment: `why do I need to implement Scanner interface` someone has to read gorm source code to check if it asserts the value type to scannable before inserting data.

Comment: Yes tried reading it mostly callback .. stuff.. I don't have a proper doc somewhere explaining the how gorm internally work.

Comment: It's all on github. "Use the source" :)

Comment: it is also a very important skill.

Comment: see the last answer